# Which Layout should be used?

Tags: java

I'm kind of new to the whole "how to arrange your components" thing in JAVA and I couldn't figure out how to realise the following JFrame (I can't post images so I just put the link)
[image: http://oi58.tinypic.com/10qjkpg.jpg]

I tried to be as precise as possible about what I already did.
I would like your advice about how to arrange the green part.
Thanks!

EDIT: as some people rightfully said, I didn't put the code of what I did. Here it is:

```
public Frame(){
        this.setTitle("Small application");
        this.setSize(445, 500);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setResizable(false);

        JPanel container = new JPanel();
        container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Title
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Welcome to this application");
        title.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        title.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,50));
        title.setFont(new Font("Courrier",Font.BOLD,20));
        container.add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        //Center part
        JPanel centerPart = new JPanel();
        JLabel cell1 = new JLabel("Enter all measurements:");
        cell1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
        JLabel cell2 = new JLabel("Please, select the files...");
        cell2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,20));
        cell2.setBackground(Color.white);
        cell2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        cell2.setOpaque(true);
        JButton cell3 = new JButton("Browse");
        cell3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,20));
        centerPart.add(cell1);
        centerPart.add(cell2);
        centerPart.add(cell3);
        container.add(centerPart, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        /*
         * I need your help here :)
         * I can't figure out how to put the image and the text next to it
         */ 

        //Bottom part
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        JButton graph = new JButton("Graph");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        bottom.add(graph);
        bottom.add(exit);
        container.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        this.setContentPane(container);
    }
```

Comment: Please don't dump us onto that ad-ridden site to look at your layout.

Comment: So, you are asking how to layout the central part? If so, it might be useful to provide a concrete example how this should look, instead of putting your question in that place.

Comment: Couldn't you just create an individual JPanel for the central part and then give the panel its own layout, then do BorderLayout.SOUTH when in that JPanel. Don't wanna put this as the answer since I don't have eclipse in front of me at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For most practical cases, you use *multiple, nested containers*, with a LayoutManager suited to the layout *within* each container.

Each LayoutManager does *one* specific job, in practice you often want differnt regions of a UI layouted in different ways. So for each region use a separate Container (e.g. JPanel) and set a LayoutManager that suits your layout requirements.

The big hurdle for beginners seems to be to get the point that LayoutManagers can (and often must) be used with nested containers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I understood that but what I would like to know is which LayoutManager would suit the best my green part.

Here is how I see it but I really don't know how to realize that. Please, tell me what you think about it :) [link]http://s4.uploads.im/AIm6l.png

PS: I still can't put image but I changed the hosting website and I don't see any adds :)

Comment: @SoufianeKharroubi The layout in your image could be realized with a GridBagLayout in a single panel (GridBagLayout is very *powerful*, but can be hard to master), or just use BorderLayout, put a JPanel (maybe FlowLayout) in the NORTH with the buttons inside, Icon in the WEST and the text use a JLabel (make use of its HTML capabilities to format the text) in the CENTER. The general strategy is *divide and conquer* (as always).

Comment: Do you have any good website to learn how to master GridLayout? If not, I'll just search it on google ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JPanel

- Create the JPanel
- Place your JPanel into your JFrame
- Position the labels, button, textfield onto the newly created JPanel.

It should do the trick. and it is pretty basic. You should be able to do the code on your own!

Comment: I just commented that xD

Comment: lololol, when i was typing in my answer, your comment didnt come up until i submitted my answer, but still it was a basic question :3